# Comma separated list of column names of a table

Tags: oracle

I am unable to get me a comma separated list of column names, given a table name. Any references are appreciated.

So my end result should be a sql statement in oracle which when run, will give me a comma separated list of column names in a given table. (so I can copy paste the list elsewhere)

**edit:**

So if my table looks like this:
table1(fieidl1,field2,field3)

I am looking to get a string like "field1,field2,field3"

so I can plug in to a separate sql statement to select the fields from the table in that order.

Comment: Have you tried `SET COLSEP ,` ?

Comment: Better to mention the DB version. Features like `LISTAGG` works with 11g onwards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `USER_TAB_COLS` from oracle dictionary and `LISTAGG` like this:

```
SELECT LISTAGG (COLUMN_NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_ID) 
FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE'
```

Comment: `LISTAGG` works with 11g onwards. Better to mention the DB version.

Answer (score 3):

```
select wm_concat(COLUMN_NAME) 
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME='MyTable';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your trying to export a query in *.csv format. If so, you can use the `SPOOL` command to do this.

```
SPOOL "C:\file\location\...\file.csv"
SELECT /*csv*/ * from your_table_name;
SPOOL OFF;
```

For more information, and examples look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12043.htm). More [examples](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/formatting-query-results-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer/).

Comment: I am looking for just the column names, not the table contents. I am not interested in porting to excel file. I just need a comma separated list of columns. some kind of massaging of information_schema.columns eqiuvalent so the result set of columns can be made into a single row, comma separated

Answer (score 0):

This solution of mine works with old version of oracle as well.***:)***

```
with a as (
select rownum r,column_name from cols where table_name ='TableName')
,b as (
select SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(column_name, ',') Fields,rownum rn from a
start with r=1
CONNECT BY PRIOR r = r-1 ),c as (
select * from b order by 2 desc) select Fields from c where rownum =1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,COLUMN_NAME,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME).GetClobVal(),',')
FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'